# If I zoom to far out everything dissapears

Tags: animation

If I zoom out too far, all objects disappear, how can I adjust this so that I can see them from further away, so that the view is simply bigger?

Thx for our help

Comment: Please use the search before posting a new question. Does the suggested duplicate address your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the *Properties Panel* of the *3D View* and open up the *View Category*. There you can find two values: **Clip Start** and **Clip End** as part of the *View Panel*. Just increase the **End** value to expand the *Clipping Distance* of the *3D View*.

Comment: Millard thank you again for your great support.

Comment: Glad I could help!